# SQL: Query timeout expired

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query for update table (30 columns and about 150 000 rows).

For example:

```
UPDATE tblSomeTable set F3 = @F3 where F1 = @F1
```

This query will affected about 2500 rows.

The tblSomeTable has a trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_tblSomeTable]
   ON  [dbo].[tblSomeTable]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @operationType nvarchar(1)
    declare @createDate datetime
    declare @UpdatedColumnsMask varbinary(500) = COLUMNS_UPDATED()


 -- detect operation type
if not exists(select top 1 * from inserted)
    begin
        -- delete
        SET @operationType = 'D'
        SELECT @createDate = dbo.uf_DateWithCompTimeZone(CompanyId) FROM deleted
    end 
else if not exists(select top 1 * from deleted)
    begin
        -- insert
        SET @operationType = 'I'
        SELECT @createDate = dbo..uf_DateWithCompTimeZone(CompanyId) FROM inserted
    end
else
    begin
        -- update
        SET @operationType = 'U'
        SELECT @createDate = dbo..uf_DateWithCompTimeZone(CompanyId) FROM inserted
    end


-- log data to tmp table

INSERT INTO tbl1
SELECT
    @createDate,
    @operationType,
    @status,
    @updatedColumnsMask,
    d.F1,
    i.F1,
    d.F2,
    i.F2,
    d.F3,
    i.F3,
    d.F4,
    i.F4,
    d.F5,
    i.F5,
    ...

FROM (Select 1 as temp) t
LEFT JOIN inserted i on 1=1
LEFT JOIN deleted d on 1=1  

END
```

And if I execute the update query I have a timeout.

How can I optimize a logic to avoid timeout?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS temp
        ) t
LEFT JOIN
        INSERTED i
ON      1 = 1
LEFT JOIN
        DELETED d
ON      1 = 1
```

will yield `2500 ^ 2 = 6250000` records from a cartesian product of `INSERTED` and `DELETED` (that is all possible combinations of all records in both tables), which will be inserted into `tbl1`.

Is that what you wanted to do?

Most probably, you want to join the tables on their `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
INSERT
INTO    tbl1
SELECT  @createDate,
        @operationType,
        @status,
        @updatedColumnsMask,
        d.F1,
        i.F1,
        d.F2,
        i.F2,
        d.F3,
        i.F3,
        d.F4,
        i.F4,
        d.F5,
        i.F5,
        ...
FROM    INSERTED i
FULL JOIN
        DELETED d
ON      i.id = d.id
```

This will treat update to the `PK` as deleting a record and inserting another, with a new `PK`.

Comment: Actually what is logged looks wrong to me as well, probably intended a union all there instead of the joins

Comment: @Sam: I believe each record in the log table contains both the new and the old versions of the records.

Comment: yeah I see that and I did upvote you cause it is a good answer. However the logging mechanism here seems a tad bloated, I guess the before after in the same row can save some time cause its easier to diagnose stuff (as opposed to having 2 rows)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Quassnoi, It's a good idea with "FULL JOIN".  It is helped me.

Also I try to update table in portions (1000 items in one time) to make my code works faster because for some companyId I need to update more than 160 000 rows.

Instead of old code:

```
    
UPDATE tblSomeTable set someVal = @someVal where companyId = @companyId
```

I use below one:

```
    
declare @rc integer = 0
declare @parts integer = 0
declare @index integer = 0
declare @portionSize int = 1000

-- select Ids for update
declare @tempIds table (id int)
insert into @tempIds
select id from tblSomeTable where companyId = @companyId

-- calculate amount of iterations
set @rc=@@rowcount
set @parts = @rc / @portionSize + 1

-- update table in portions
WHILE (@parts > @index)
begin

    UPDATE TOP (@portionSize) t     
    SET someVal = @someVal      
    FROM tblSomeTable t     
    JOIN @tempIds t1 on t1.id = t.id        
    WHERE companyId = @companyId        

    delete top (@portionSize) from @tempIds     
    set @index += 1         

end
```

What do you think about this? Does it make sense? If yes, how to choose correct portion size?

Or simple update also good solution? I just want to avoid locks in the future.

Thanks

Comment: look out for integer math in that division.

Comment: What criteria are used to select top N rows in the absence of `order by`? How do you make sure you are deleting the very same IDs from the table var as the ones that have just been updated in tblSomeTable?

Comment: Also, you seem to be trying to use SO as if it were a forum, which it is not, strictly speaking. I mean, you've posted additional questions as an answer, which is messing things up a bit. Normally you are supposed simply to edit your original post for additions.